# Django Nginx Gunicorn = 504 Timeout

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to publish a Django application on the production server using Nginx + Gunicorn. When I doing a simple stress test on the server (holding the F5 key for a minute) the server returns a `504 Gateway Time-out` error.  Why does this happen?  This error only appears for the user when doing multiple concurrent requests, or the system will be fully unavailable to everyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you hold down F5:

- You've started hundreds of requests.
- Those requests have filled your gunicorn request queue.
- The request handlers have not been culled as soon as the connection drops.
- Your latest requests are stuck in the queue behind all the previous requests.
- Nginx times out.
- For everyone.

Solutions:

- Set up rate-limiting buckets in Nginx, keyed on IP, such that one malicious user can't spam you with requests and DOS your site.
- Set up a global rate-limiting bucket in Nginx such that you don't overfill your request queue.
- Make Nginx serve a nice "Reddit is under heavy load" style page, so users know that this is a purposeful event

Or:

Replace gunicorn with uwsgi. It's faster, more memory efficient, integrates smoothly with nginx, and most importantly: It will kill the request handler *immediately* if the connection drops, such that F5 spam can't kill your server.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@paragsharma.py/504-gateway-timeout-django-gunicorn-nginx-4570deaf0922

504 can be caused by gunicorn timeout you need to start it with `--timeout` arg like

```
gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --timeout 300  --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```